# i want to show a modal when user lands on home page very first time

Tags: shortcode, login

what i want is when user lands on home page for very 1st time i want to show a specific modal. i managed to record the first login of user but what i cant get is how to track user first time landing on home page, below the code of tracking user first time login:

```
  add_action( 'wp_login', 'track_user_logins', 10, 2 );
   function track_user_logins( $user_login, $user ){
    if( $login_amount = get_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', true ) ){
    update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', 0 );
     } else {
    // First Login, set it to 1
    update_user_meta( $user->id, 'login_amount', 1 );
    }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to increase count when user visit home page.
Like if user 1 first time visit need to update meta with count 1.
this count need to increase every time when user visit.

so, you can easily found the users count and check also use the below condition for your model.
( $count == 1 ).

Note: this is just an example. I am assuming $count is the usermeta count.

Comment: What about guest users? They should not see the modal? Also, when you say „home page“ do you mean the Front-Page or _any_ page on your WordPress website?

Answer (score 0):

`template_redirect` is usually a good action to hook a custom callback to, when you want to conditionally add or remove template actions / parts for the current request / view as the use has been identified, the WP object is set up, and WP is getting ready to determine which template to load.

You could use this action to check, if the request is for the home page (front page) and if it is the first time for the current user. This information could be saved as a separate user meta data. For example like this,

```
// use a custom callback to check and set home page first visit flag to user
add_action('template_redirect', 'prefix_check_first_home_page_visit', 1); // mind the priority
function prefix_check_first_home_page_visit() {
    // Is home page
    if ( ! is_front_page() ) {
        return;
    }
    
    // Get user
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    // Only logged in users
    if ( ! $user->exists() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Get user meta for home page visit
    $visited_home_meta_key = 'home_page_first_visit'; // change as needed
    $has_visited_home = get_user_meta(
        $user->ID,
        $visited_home_meta_key,
        true
    );

    // Check, if user has already visited home page
    if ( $has_visited_home ) {
        return;
    }

    // Save first visit to user meta
    update_user_meta(
        $user->ID,
        $visited_home_meta_key,
        time() // e.g. timestamp when the first visit happened, change as needed
    );

    // Trigger later action
    add_filter( 'is_home_page_first_visit', '__return_true' );
}
```

I got fancy above and used a custom filter at the end of the first callback to trigger the callback below, which takes care of adding the modal html to the template. This way the code is separated into smaller pieces, which makes it easier to manage and change later.

```
// A separate function for enabling the modal
add_action('template_redirect', 'prefix_show_home_page_first_visit_modal', 10); // mind the priority
function prefix_show_home_page_first_visit_modal() {
    // Trigger modal printing conditionally
    if ( apply_filters( 'is_home_page_first_visit', false ) ) {
        // Print the modal html to the site footer for example
        add_action('wp_footer', 'prefix_render_home_page_first_visit_modal');
    }
}

function prefix_render_home_page_first_visit_modal() {
    // Get template part or echo html here
}
```